# What file path should I give for the file(preferrably json) which I have created and want to store in remote tomcat server?

Tags: java, json, file, tomcat

I have created a `JSON` file

`FileWriter fileWriter = new FileWriter("/home/something.json");`

This I have created to test my local system but when I will move to remote server, I am getting confused what `file_path` to give. As I want to create the file store it in the server and later I will move it some cloud storage. So suggest me what `file_path` should I give.
Thanks.

Comment: I guess you should make this part of your configuration. When you switch to cloud storage you will most likely need credentials and more in your config

Answer (score 1):

You could create project folder in home directory of user and store files there.

Path for project folder:

`System.getProperties("user.home") +"/project_folder");`

Comment: Please keep in mind that the user directory can be subject to synchronisation on Windows